# Python and google app engine blobproperty()

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7

I wrote some codes.

I could upload image in BobProperty.

But I cannot load image into HTML page

```
import webapp2
from google.appengine.ext import db
from google.appengine.api import images

form="""
<form action="/" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <div><label>Avatar:</label></div>
        <div><input type="file" name="img"/></div>
            <input type="submit" value="switch">
</form>
"""
```

create BlobProperty

```
class Greeting(db.Model):
    avatar = db.BlobProperty()
```

for image

```
class Image(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        posts = db.GqlQuery("select * from Greeting")
        for post in posts:

            self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'image/jpg'
            self.response.out.write(post)
```

for put image into datastore

```
class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.out.write(form)
    def post(self):
        avatar = images.resize(self.request.get('img'), 32, 32)
        greeting = Greeting(avatar=avatar)
        greeting.avatar = db.Blob(avatar)
        greeting.put()    


app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainHandler),
                               ('/img', Image),],
                               debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make the following changes:

```
class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.out.write(form)
    def post(self):
        avatar = images.resize(self.request.get('img'), 32, 32)
        greeting = Greeting()
        greeting.avatar = db.Blob(avatar)
        greeting.put()
```

Also, in the handler that serves the image:

```
class Image(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        posts = db.GqlQuery("select * from Greeting")
        for post in posts:

            self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'image/jpg'
            self.response.out.write(post.avatar)
```